# Detect if Mod_Security Is Installed With PHP?

Tags: php, mod-security

Is there any simple way to detect if mod_security is installed & enabled using just PHP? Ideally without any exec() terminal type commands to be executed.

Some people have recommended using apache_get_modules() but this specific web-host does not allow it to show. This is also mentioned by other users here: http://www.devcomments.com/apache_get_modules-solution-to130703.htm

Answer (score 5):

Try the [`apache_get_modules`function](http://php.net/apache_get_modules) to get an array of the loaded modules. If that module is loaded but not listed there, you might want to try [`phpinfo`](http://php.net/phpinfo) with `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES)` instead:

```
ob_start();
phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);
$contents = ob_get_clean();
$moduleAvailable = strpos($contents, 'mod_security') !== false;
```

Comment: Should be noted this can be done only if PHP is installed as an Apache module.

Comment: This function doesn't seem to work correctly for all hosts. Some hosts appear to not return all of the apache mods using this function for some reason.  Another post on it: http://www.devcomments.com/apache_get_modules-solution-to130703.htm

Any Other Ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You can do just create a test.php file and use..

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

And look at the apache2handler, and look at: Loaded modules.. something like this...

http://gyazo.com/bcba303469f23671f7213e1478788cbd.png

-Mike

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for PHP-FPM, in which case there is no Apache2handler block

Answer (score 2):

Grasping at straws here.

Try having your script make a request to itself (via `file_get_contents` or maybe the cURL extension) that would trip mod_security.  If it returns a 403 (or whatever mod_security's default response is), that should be enough information for you to go on...

Answer (score 0):

You can search the get_loaded_extensions() function and use array_intersect() which will return matching values in an array else an empty array if it does not find anything matching.

```
$modSecurity = !empty(array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', get_loaded_extensions()), array('mod_security', 'mod security'))) ? true : false;
```