# 403 Forbidden Error for Joomla administrator

Tags: php, joomla

Let me preface this with, only *one* user is having this issue. Everyone else can log-in to the Joomla administration just fine.

Originally when I found that the single user was receiving a 403 when landing on the administrator page, I checked to make sure all directories were writable as per the directories listed under *Site Information*. I've also confirmed that the administrator directory has 755 permissions, and that the user has cleared her cache.

**Also**, the site was recently moved from one server to another. Changed the A record on the old server to the IP of the new server.

Thoughts as to why a single user would receive a 403 error only in the Joomla administration page?

Comment: can you check access logs and see what is written there when it happens? also, do you have something like `mod_security` enabled?

Comment: There is nothing in the logs that isn't from my IP.

Comment: all users access with the same ip?

Comment: Nope, they do not. How do I check if mod_security is enabled?

Comment: if they do not, then how come in access log you have only your ip listed? access logs should list **all** access informations for your website, whether successful or unnsuccessful. for checking mod_security, try this for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182500/detect-if-mod-security-is-installed-with-php

Comment: Well the only 2 errors in the log are from when I purposely used incorrect credentials to force an error in the log. Other than that, there are no other errors.

Comment: Interesting, it has only shown errors. Although the file is called, error.php, under `/logs` -- the directory that comes with Joomla.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26188/discussion-between-josh-and-marko-d)

Comment: access.log is _not_ the same as error.log

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After chat discussion, it turns out that the server has been moved recently and since then the problem started.

The problem seems to be cached dns on the user's side, so the user has to clear dns cache, or wait for the provider to clear dns cache

Comment: @Josh eh. so it was resolving to the correct ip? if you want we can continue the discussion on chat

Comment: @Josh hey, I don't think I will be available today anymore, but in the meantime, just make sure her `ping yourdomain.com` and `ping www.yourdomain.com` give the same result as for you! (and she can try without www prefix to open admin page)

Comment: I want to guess *one* of the things you suggested worked, because my client emailed me this morning confirming that she can log-in to the administrator, even though I haven't suggested any additional fixes over the weekend.

Comment: @Josh Good to hear! I was wondering if the issue was resolved, I'm glad it works now!

Comment: I don't know how/why it was resolved, but I'm glad too! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you look inside your administrator folder, see if there is a .htaccess file in there.
If there is, download it and open it up. 
Look to  you can see the following rule:

Deny from ALL
Allow from xxx.xxx.xx.xx

This will block everybody from accessing the Administrator page on the web except the IP addresses that follows the ALLOW.

Add the users IP address (he can find what it is by going to www.ipchicken.com).

So if there were two existing Allow from (ip address here), you would copy the whole line and paste it underneath the last one, then change the IP address.

Save and upload back to the administrator folder and try that.